# Mem-map slows down when deep in the matrix

Tags: python, numpy, memory-mapping

So I have a very large matrix (120000 x 120000), and I am running a script on this entire matrix that compares an element to every other element. Because I cannot hold the entire thing in memory, I use memmap. I also periodically flush the matrix to ensure that if the computer crashes or something I don't lose all the data. However, I have noticed that the "deeper" I get into the matrix, so to speak, the time it takes to flush the data increases. Eventually, it takes as long as up to five minutes to save my results. Woudl anyone know why it is doing this? Is there a better way I can be doing this? I'll post some code, but I am fairly certain I am not doing anything "wrong".

```
OUT_DIR = '/media/sf_3dAnalysis/simMatrix/'
SIM_FILE = 'similarity.npy'
data = np.lib.format.open_memmap(OUT_DIR+SIM_FILE, mode='w+', dtype='float32', shape=(120821,120821))
#After processing a certain amount of indices, I go to flush the data.
data.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

mmap is nice for problems with a smallish locality of reference - one that will fit in physmem.  However, it sounds like you're using mmap for 53 gigabytes of data, and the locality of reference is not good.

You'll probably have to accept a bit of a performance penalty for this workload if you're committed to mmap.

One thing that might help *some*, is writing a class that will keep as much of the matrix as possible in memory (maybe the first rows), and put the rest on disk (the rest of the rows), uncached (perhaps using O_DIRECT).

In your case, caching the whole thing will probably just cause virtual memory thrashing unless you have an atypically large physmem.  However, 53+ gig of physmem is probably not out of reach if you have the budget.

If you decide to go the O_DIRECT route, check this out:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/odirect/

Comment: Would you have any other suggestions besides mmap for the task I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

You could try sharding memory maps across multiple files. IF when writing to memory maps the slow down per flush is greater than linear relative to the size of the first axis, then this approach should work.

```
# Shard memmaps across multiple files
memmaps = {}
partitions_per_map
first_axis_length = 1000000
for ii in range(first_axis_length//partitions_per_map):
    memmaps[ii] = np.memmap(f'{<some_dir>}{ii*partitions_per_map}_{(ii+1)*partitions_per_map}.npy',
                         dtype='uint8', mode='w+',
                         shape=(partitions_per_map,<rest of shape>)
# Remainder
ii = first_axis_length//partitions_per_map
memmaps[ii] = np.memmap(f'{<some_dir>}{ii*partitions_per_map}_{(ii+1)*partitions_per_map}.npy',
                         dtype='uint8', mode='w+',
                         shape=(partitions_per_map,<rest of shape>))
# Keep track of batches added to sharded memory maps
batch_counts = {ii:0 for ii in range(len(memmaps))}

# Flushes done on independent basis for each partition or globally
flush_method = "global"#"independent"
flush_every_x_batches = 200
```

Then when writing to memory maps:

```
# Determine relevant cache shards to add to
partitions_to_write = ix_//partitions_per_map
for p in np.unique(partitions_to_write):
    cache_ = memmaps[p]
    bool_arr = (ix_ >= p*partitions_per_map) & (ix_ < (p+1)*partitions_per_map)
    global_slice_ = np.s_[bool_arr]
    ix_ss = ix_[global_slice_]
    ix_offset = p * partitions_per_map
    cache_[ix_ss-ix_offset, existing_neighbors[global_slice_]] = data_to_write[bool_arr].astype(np.uint8)
    batch_counts[p] += 1

    if flush_method == 'independent':
        # Flush changes if using memmap (every x batches per map)
        if batch_counts[p] > 0 and batch_counts[p] % flush_every_x_batches == 0:
            cache_.flush()

# Flush changes on global batch counts
if flush_method == 'global':
    if bi > 0 and bi % flush_every_x_batches == 0:
        for cache_ in memmaps.values():
            cache_.flush()
```